# Cloudant Query $gt (greater than) string phrase with spaces

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant

Using Cloudant Query, i'm trying to get all documents with text greater than a specified phrase:

```
{
  "selector":{
    "name":{
      "$gt":"Test for pagination"
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "name:string":"asc"
    }
  ],
  "limit":5,
  "use_index":[
    "NameQueryIndex",
    "nameQueryIndex_v1"
  ]
}
```

However, i'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": "text_search_error",
  "reason": "Cannot parse '(name_3astring:{Test\\ for\\ pagination TO u0x10FFFF])': Encountered \" <RANGE_GOOP> \"pagination \"\" at line 1, column 27.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"]\" ...\n    \"}\" ...\n    "
}
```

When i remove the whitespace (i.e. `Testforpagination`), it works fine

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, the documentation suggests that what you're attempting should work. I suggest filing a support ticket: support@cloudant.com

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a bug with how they interpret the range behind the scenes. They should probably be wrapping it in qutations, i.e. `{"Test\\ for\\ pagination" TO u0x10FFFF]` instead of `{Test\\ for\\ pagination TO u0x10FFFF]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a view on your database and using the same logic on your mapping function. Then access these documents using REST. You don't need the query and the documents would be pulled out much faster.